# Sphinx code documentation build failing in GitLab CI/CD

Tags: python, gitlab, gitlab-ci, python-sphinx, autodoc

I am trying to create some documentation for some code written, specifically for a file called pipeline.py. Now I am using GitLab to host the documentation online. There are only two parts of the documentation, a step-by-step-guide and a code documentation. The guide works fine and is rendered great using Sphinx ReadTheDocs. The code documentation however is failing, not rendering, and I am getting this error in the CI logs:

[image: CI failing for autodoc]

I was just wondering whether anyone had seen this error. This is what my .gitlab-ci.yml file looks like:

[image: yml file example]